# PowerShell GUI, moving window by clicking borderless windows form

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I want to use borderless windows form for my GUI, however I would like also to be able to move window just by clicking on the form itself.

Do you know how to achieve? In Google I have found only solutions for C# or C++.

Comment: How did you create your GUI at the moment?

Comment: using windows form, mostly using sapien software to do it however its trial version so i cannot add a lot of objects there :)

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial from foxdeploy https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/ It will show you how to create a GUi with WPF very simple

Comment: but i wanted to do it using windwos form because im already familiar with

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you can use this type function where with each click the form moves 5 pix:

```
$MainForm.add_click({($x = $MainForm.location.x+5); $y = $MainForm.location.y; $Mainform.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)})
```